# Error while inserting eps file

Tags: pdftex, eps

I tried to install basic MikTex version 2.9.7152-x64. It crashed with windows API 5 error. I had a previously downloaded basic MikTex 2.9.7031-x64. I installed it, got the issue resolved, then I updated everything through MikTex Console. Now while compiling my document using TexMaker, I am getting 'Package pdftex.def Error: File `v_c-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found: using draft setting. \includegraphics[scale=0.52]{v_c}'. v_c is a .eps file saved in the same directory as the tex file. I've already inserted several eps files without any error whatsoever. Those previously compiled files appear just fine. Help needed.

Comment: compile once on a command line to get (perhaps) better error messages (I have no problems in a current miktex).

Comment: You can also check the log file (probably somewhere near the end) to see if there are any error messages there related to the eps conversion. It is possible that the eps file is invalid for some reason which causes the conversion to fail. To diagnose the problem, you can also try to open the eps file in an image viewer, or open a command prompt, go to your folder, and run `epstopdf v_c.eps test.pdf` to see if the conversion itself can be performed without errors.

Comment: Also make sure the file (`v_c.eps`) actually has the extension `.eps`, and not just `v_c` as filename. In the LaTeX code (`\includegraphics[scale=0.52]{v_c}`) it is recommended to leave out the extension, but the actual file does need to have the extension.